# Is it possible to have a textbox item equal another value

Tags: mysql, vb.net, textbox, calculator

Can't seem to find anything on the internet. I have an automatic input textbox which will display a job given what I select in my combobox. So if the customer id I selected from the combobox was 1 it will display what that customers job was.

So the textbox may display either:
Book Keeping or Accounting

Each of these has a cost for example book keeping is £100 an hour. Then on my form you use the numeric up down to select the hours it took the person to do the customers job. If 2 is selected then I have another textbox which will display the value of £100*2 = £200

Is it possible to do this, I have got no idea.

From a bit of research this is my code, but I can't make it work

`If txtservice1.Text = "Book Keeping" Then
            txtservicepayment.Text = 100 * NumericUpDown1.Value
        End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the total value first and use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to concatenate the calculated value with `£`. This code should work and it has to be inside [NumericUpDown.ValueChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) handler, something like:

```vb
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _
    Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged

    If txtservice1.Text = "Book Keeping" Then 
        txtservicepayment.Text = string.Format("£{0}", 100 * NumericUpDown1.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It comes up with the £ but when I select a value on the numeric up down the calculated value does not appear in the text box?

Comment: What's the value of `numericupdown1.Value` when you select a value on the numeric up down? Is it a number?

Comment: Yep a single digit number

Comment: The above code will work if `numericupdown1.Value` is `"1"` or `"2"` or any other numbers. Where's the code located? Are you using [NumericUpDown.ValueChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or not?

Comment: Thank you for that, silly mistake by me, I had it in the form load

Comment: I have included the `ValueChanged` event handler code.